# Phaser update sprite texture

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have a problem updating a sprite.

I created a function to change clothes. This should work like:

```
// Something like this.
pet = pet_with_hat
```

There is code at https://github.com/futer/pandachii in in js/main.js, line 387.

When I write this:

```
this.pet = this.game.add.sprite(90,90, 'pet_black_hat')
```

There is an error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'health' of undefined
 GameState.update @ main.js:194
 Phaser.StateManager.update @ phaser.js:16628
 Phaser.Game.update @ phaser.js:23092
 Phaser.RequestAnimationFrame.updateRAF @ phaser.js:41421
 _onLoop @ phaser.js:41407
```

How do I change the sprite image for this pet to another?

I will be grateful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is you're replacing the existing `this.pet` with a new `Phaser.Sprite`, which then doesn't have any of the custom properties you set.

**For Phaser 2:**

You can use [`loadTexture()`](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.6/Phaser.Component.LoadTexture.html#loadTexture) to replace the image used for the pet sprite.

```
this.pet.loadTexture('pet_black_hat');
```

**For Phaser 3:**

You can use [`setTexture()`](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Matter.Sprite.html#setTexture__anchor) to replace the image used for the pet sprite.

```
this.pet.setTexture('pet_black_hat');
```

Comment: I'd also highly recommend updating the version of Phaser that you use. Some of the functionality is now deprecated in certain browsers, and you'd be missing out on performance improvements. Having gone through a number of tutorials, the number of breaking changes is generally relatively small, and they're easy to find solutions to when they do occur.

Comment: Aww... That is so simply solve :(
Thanks you dude very much :)

Comment: Also another tip: you are using a lot of small sprite files, which could make loading and performance slower. I'd recommend using something like [Leshy SpriteSheet Tool](http://www.leshylabs.com/apps/sstool/)
to put them all into one single file, save the sprite-map as a JSON-TP-Hash, and then use `Phaser.Atlas` to load the sprites.

Answer (score 14):

For Phaser 3 you can use [setTexture](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite.html#setTexture__anchor):

```
carSprite.setTexture('tank')
```

Answer (score 3):

- If you've added the **new** image using `scene.add.image(...)` then you can use,
  `carSprite.setTexture('tank')`
- If you want to select a different sprite in the same texture atlas that you loaded with `scene.load.atlas(...)`, then you can call `carSprite.setFrame('tank')`
- If you want to select a sprite in a completely different texture atlas, then you can call, `carSprite.setTexture('newTextureAtlasKey', 'tank')`

Hope this helps.